# How to execute a LIKE query against a DECIMAL (or INTEGER) field?

Tags: sql, informix

Is it possible to execute a LIKE statement against a table column that contains DECIMAL types? Or else, what would be the best way to select matching rows given a number in a decimal (or integer) field?

E.g.:

```
Name  Age
...   ...
John  25
Mary  76
Jim   45
Erica 34
Anna  56
Bob   55
```

Executing something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE age LIKE 5` would return:

```
Name  Age
John  25
Jim   45
Anna  56
Bob   55
```

Comment: What would a `LIKE` against such a field even mean? What does it mean above? Items that _end_ with 5? Items that are divisible by 5?

Comment: Basically I want to search against a column with DECIMALS for any occurrence of the input number (in the given order), either at the beginning, or end or middle.

Comment: What does the data represent? That is, why is it a DECIMAL column? What you need to do implies it is the _wrong_ data type.

Comment: @Oded I understand, but imagine it is a legacy database, so changing the column type won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve, but based on the example query, the filtering you need to do should be achievable using normal arithmetic operators.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(age, 10) = 5 -- All records where the age ends in 5
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(age, 5) = 0 -- All records where age is divisible by 5
```

---

Now that you clarified that though you are using a `DECIMAL` field you are not actually using it as a numeric value (as if you would, the requirement wouldn't exist), the answers given by others are reasonable - convert the field to a text value and use `LIKE` on it.

Alternatively, change the type of the field to something that is more suitable to the way you are using it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the question with a more clear case of what I would expect the result to be. Thanks, though.

Comment: Understood. I figure it was a long shot to have that sort of functionality.

Comment: @rae1n - That's what happens when data is not modelled correctly (such as phone numbers in integer fields... causing leading 0s to disappear).

Comment: This answer only applies to the numbers that end with 5, not containing 5.

Comment: @dmaij - The first part of the answer, the one that assumed one is dealing with numbers normally. The second part is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your decimal field to varchar and then apply like.

Comment: Probably the worst way to do what the OP _actually_ wants.

Comment: @Oded Actually I've seen a couple of solutions doing just that. However, doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: @rae1n - That's my point. When dealing with numbers, converting to strings is hardly going to be the best option.

Comment: @Oded, Your solution does not work if 5 is inside the string.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a query

```
select name from table where age like '%5%'
```

you could achieve this (at least in mysql and db2)
But if you prefer to match a number you should use something like:

```
select name from table where age > minimum and age < maximum
```

Or try to compare against a modulo if you are really interested in querying on the last number.

Comment: I want to be able to select all rows that match the input number anywhere in it, like a LIKE statement against a string would do.

Comment: DB2 accepts the first example line, I don't know about informix since I don't have it here.

Comment: Informix complains when using wildcards against a non-character type.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to cast to varchar then. I assume db2 does the same under the surface after all (except without the complaint).